# Tomcat 6 broken images

Tags: java, images

I am using Tomcat 6 to serve both static content and dynamic content. For some reason, from time to time, I see that images are broken.

It usually happens when I copy and paste the image URL to the browser. When I refresh the image appears. The server has zero load on it.

Has anyone encountered such issue with Tomcat?

Comment: One possibility is that you accessed the image URLs when they were not available (server not up, still working on setup, etc.), and the browser cached the response.  Refreshing then bypasses the cache and gets the now available image.

Answer (score 1):

When a Tomcat 6 server is freshly started, or when a web app is dynamically loaded, the content is not accessible for a number of seconds.

I sometimes see this type of problem on my development server around the time when I am restarting the web app.